# PROBLEM :: Enable SSH for hadoop with new key

Tags: ssh, 14.04, vmware, hadoop

I followed [michael noll's tutorial](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) for installing hadoop,

I created hadoop user as 'hduser' and generated key, but I am stuck in here,
when i try to enable ssh access with generated key by using,

```
hduser@arul-virtual-machine:~$ cat $HOME/ .ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/ .ssh/authorized_keys
```

and I got response as,

```
-su: /home/hduser/: Is a directory
```

I am using vmware workstation with ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't a space in between `$HOME` and `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and also between `$HOME` and `.ssh/authorized_keys`, so the actual command is:

```
cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

(you could copy-paste the above command).

This appends the contents of `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`